# sql updating table b after selecting ids from table A

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, select

I have two tables

Table A

```
   Pid  Name
    1        A
    3        B
    4        C
```

Table B

```
  Pid  Name  Status
   1        A      0
   2        B      0
   3        C      0
   4        D      0
```

I want to update the Status of Table B from 0 to 1 by selecting all the Table A pid.

For Example. Table A does not have PId = 2 so Pid  = 2 of Table B should not update.

I have tried the following query with no luck

```
UPDATE Table_B 
SET 
Status = 1
WHERE Table_B.Pid = (SELECT  Table_A.Pid 
                             FROM   Table_A 
                             WHERE  Table_A.Pid = Table_B.Pid)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
UPDATE Table_B 
SET 
Status = 1
WHERE Table_B.Pid in (SELECT Table_A.Pid FROM Table_A )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner joins even during updates

```
  Update B
  SET Status = 1
  From Table_B as B
  INNER JOIN Table_A as A
  ON A.Pid = B.Pid
  WHERE B.Status = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
UPDATE B 
SET 
Status = 1
from Table_B B
inner join Table_A A on A.pid = B.pid
WHERE  B.Status = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a simplified example, but I see 2 problems with this. First, the Name column should not live in 2 different places - only 1.  Second, Status should be calculated when needed, not updated.

So it should be more like:

```
SELECT b.Pid,
b.Name,
CASE WHEN a.Pid IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Status
FROM Table_B
LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.Pid
      FROM Table_A
      GROUP BY a.Pid) AS a
ON b.Pid = a.Pid
```